# Values won't appear in the state(react)

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, state, push

SOS! Here i have favourite meals from local storage assigned to favs state. I then use my favs to fetch a meal for each favs value. My favs state updates on initial render, but fetchedMeals is not. It updates only after SECOND render. It seems that i have problem somewhere with async function. Would appreciate any help. Will provide with more details immediately if needed.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from '../Home/NavBar';

function Favourites() {
  const [favs, setFavs] = useState([]);
  const [fetchedMeals, setFetchedMeals] = useState([]);

  const getFavsFromLs = () => {
    let itemsFromLs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favs')) || [];
    setFavs(itemsFromLs);
  };
  const fetchMeal = async (mealName) => {
    const linkByMealName = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${mealName}`;
    const res = await fetch(linkByMealName);
    const meal = await res.json();
    return meal.meals[0];
  };

  const getFavMeals = async () => {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
      fetchMeal(favs[i]).then((res) => items.push(res));
    }
    setFetchedMeals(items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavsFromLs(); //Moved getFavMeals to another useEffect
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {// New use effect that listens favs
    if (favs && favs.length) {
      getFavMeals();
    }
  }, [favs]);
 
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <section className="section">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="container col l12">
            {fetchedMeals.map((meal) => {
                const { strMeal, strMealThumb, idMeal } = meal;
                return (
                  <Link to={`/favourites/${strMeal}`}>
                    <div class="col s12 m6 l3" key={idMeal}>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                          <img src={strMealThumb} alt="img"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <h5 className="truncate center">{strMeal}</h5>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Favourites;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setting state is an asynchronous you need to make `useEffect` for `favs` and when they are set from `localStorage` you can make that `getFavMeals` and at that point `favs` will have data.

Also doing `console.log` immediately after setting state will also show old value, because it needs to rerender. You are trying also on `console.log(fetchedMeals)`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from '../Home/NavBar';

function Favourites() {
  const [favs, setFavs] = useState([]);
  const [fetchedMeals, setFetchedMeals] = useState([]);

  const getFavsFromLs = () => {
    let itemsFromLs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favs')) || [];
    setFavs(itemsFromLs);
  };
  const fetchMeal = async (mealName) => {
    const linkByMealName = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${mealName}`;
    const res = await fetch(linkByMealName);
    const meal = await res.json();
    console.log(meal.meals[0]);
    return meal.meals[0];
  };

  const getFavMeals = async () => {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
      fetchMeal(favs[i]).then((res) => items.push(res));
    }
    setFetchedMeals(items);
    console.log(fetchedMeals);
    console.log(items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavsFromLs(); //Moved getFavMeals to another useEffect
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {// New use effect that listens favs
    if (favs && favs.length) {
      getFavMeals();
    }
  }, [favs]);

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <section className="section">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="container col l12">
            {fetchedMeals &&
              fetchedMeals.map((meal) => {
                console.log(meal);
                const { strMeal, strMealThumb, idMeal } = meal;
                console.log(meal);
                return (
                  <Link to={`/favourites/${strMeal}`}>
                    <div class="col s12 m6 l3" key={idMeal}>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                          <img src={strMealThumb} alt="img"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <h5 className="truncate center">{strMeal}</h5>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Favourites;
```